# how to change android app name in the build gradle file

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm creating different flavors using gradle for 2 small android apps ,i wanna just know if i  can  edit app name on the xml file in the build.gradle , for my different flavors .

Comment: I have answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24785270/how-to-change-app-name-per-gradle-build-type/63449478#63449478), you can go through my answer, it might help you.

Answer (score 15):

What do you mean by `app name`? the application package name in the manifest or the application name as it appears in the launcher?

If the former, do:

```
android {
  productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
      packageName 'com.example.flavor1'
    }
    flavor2 {
      packageName 'com.example.flavor2'
    }
  }
}
```

It's possible to override the app name as well but you'd have to provide a flavor overlay resource instead.

So create the following files:

- `src/flavor1/res/values/strings.xml`
- `src/flavor2/res/values/strings.xml`

And in them just override the string resource that contains your app name (the one that your manifest use for the main activity label through something like `@string/app_name`). You can also provide different translations as needed.

Comment: exactly , i'm looking for a solution to override app name , i used copy method , as a result i have a new folder containing a new string.xml modified , containing the new app name ! the problem is how can i avoid this creation of that new file. i like just to replace it.

Comment: This is the best way to do it. Hacking around to edit the file in place is not a good idea as it'll break detection of incremental builds.

Comment: find app/src/freefacebook/res/values/strings.xml -type f -exec  perl -pi -w -e 's/My_Application/free_facebook/g' {} \;

Comment: Update: the Android gradle plugin now can define a resource like: resValue <type>,<name>,<value> to provide the string from your gradle script.

Comment: @HassanIbraheem document reference please?

Comment: @PrakashNadar you can find it on this page: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system under release "0.8.1"

Answer (score 12):

You can use `resValue`, eg.

```
debug {
    resValue 'string', 'app_name', '"MyApp (Debug)"'`
}
release {
    resValue 'string', 'app_name', '"MyApp"'
}
```

Make sure your AndroidManifest uses `android:label="@string/app_name"` for the application, and remove app_name from strings.xml as it will conflict with gradle's generated `strings.xml` when it tries to merge them.

Comment: This is actually a very good answer. I don't know why people are voting up  based answers based on manually creating contents of `strings.xml`, but resValue should be the right way to go since you can put the actual values in `gradle.properties`.

Comment: In my case, I hade to add parentheses after resValue (I used resValue as a function).

Answer (score 5):

Actually... For a more definitive explanation;

In **main** build.gradle :

```
ext {
    APP_NAME = "My Fabulous App"
    APP_NAME_DEBUG = "My Fabulous App debug"
}
```

In **app** build.gradle :

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: APP_NAME_DEBUG]
        }
        release {
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: APP_NAME]
        }
    }
}
```

so in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    ...
    android:label="${appName}"
    >
```

is possible. Voilà! you have different application names for release and debug.

Comment: In my opinion, this is the best approach, because it allows to have a localized app name for release builds (`manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "@string/app_name"]`), and a non localized one for debug builds.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on Tom's, it works the best and you can work with `gradle.properties` to allow further animation in build process.

In `build.gradle`:

```groovy
debug {
  resValue 'string', 'app_name', APP_NAME
}
```

In `gradle.properties`:

```groovy
APP_NAME="Template 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.myapp"> 


<application
    tools:replace="android:label"
    android:label="${appName}"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

 <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"      
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:label="${appName}"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Gradle

```
buildTypes {
    release {
         minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
         signingConfig signingConfigs.release
//       manifestPlaceholders = [appName: appConfig.appName]
         manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "Your app Name"]

    }

    debug {
         signingConfig signingConfigs.release
//       manifestPlaceholders = [appName: appConfig.appName]
         manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "Your app Name"] 

    }
}
```