# How to change app name per Gradle build type

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to figure out a way to be able to change my application's app name per build type in gradle.

For instance, I would like the debug version to have `<APP_NAME>-debug` and the qa version to have `<APP-NAME>-QA`.

I am familiar with:

```
debug {
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        versionNameSuffix '-DEBUG'
}
```

However, I can't seem to find a gradle command to apply the change of the app when in the launcher.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

If by "app name", you mean `android:label` on `<application>`, the simplest solution is to have that point at a string resource (e.g., `android:label="@string/app_name"`), then have a different version of that string resource in a `src/debug/` sourceset.

You can see that in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.7/Gradle/HelloBuildType), where I have a replacement for `app_name` in `src/debug/res/values/strings.xml`, which will be applied for `debug` builds. `release` builds will use the version of `app_name` in `src/main/`.

Comment: wouldn't this solution imply that we would have to add an extra strings.xml for each translation? that could become a pain to maintain...

Comment: @sfera: First, you are welcome to isolate this string in its own resource file if you want. Second, this is only for one string. Third, this is only for the build types where you want to replace that string. Fourth, unless you have a development team without a common language, you would not need to translate non-`release` strings.

Comment: Isolating the string sounds like a good idea. Thanks for that! As for the non-``release`` part, I see that a bit differently as one might want to also test for localization issues while allowing the "release" and "test" builds to coexist on the same device. In such a case both builds might end up with the same launcher label, probably causing some confusion. That is what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: @sfera: "That is what I was trying to avoid" -- so, don't translate this one string. The test on that string will be invalid anyway, as by definition, it is not the string you want to use in `release` mode. And only use this string resource for `app_name`, not for any other role.

Comment: We are probably talking about different things. I didn't intend to translate the "DEBUG" string. But the app launcher label is certainly localized for the release build. Now - assuming that my app label is "AppName" - I would like to have "AppName-DEBUG" for debug builds with the french label of something like "AppNom-DEBUG" and the german label "AppNamen-DEBUG".

Comment: @sfera: You will never ship an app with "AppNom-DEBUG". You might ship an app with "AppNom". Testing "AppNom-DEBUG", therefore, is unnecessary. You are certainly welcome to translate a debug version of `app_name`, even though it is not necessary (e.g., you have French or German developers who do not speak English and therefore need to have it translated). For testing to see if the unmodified `release` version of `app_name` works, with its translations, test the `release` build, or create a `near-release` build type that just adds the app ID suffix and leaves the strings alone.

Comment: When having flavors in the project, putting `strings.xml` in `/src/debug/res/values/`doesn't work. Instead, you need to specify the flavor name in front of the build type, e.g.: if you have a flavor called Premium then the folder name should be: `premiumDebug`. @CommonsWare, perhaps you should update your answer accordingly.

Comment: @NimrodDayan: No, that's still supposed to work, assuming that you do not need different names per actual build variant. If you want the same name for all `debug` builds regardless of flavor, my answer is correct. If you are having problems getting this to work, file a fresh Stack Overflow question with a [mcve].

Comment: You're right, it does work. I didn't notice, but in Android Studio, the current build type was something else than debug at the time I tried it. After changing that back to the `flavorDebug`, it seemed to do the trick.

Comment: @CommonsWare Link is dead. 404

Answer (score 200):

You can use something like this

```
 buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        versionNameSuffix '-DEBUG'
        resValue "string", "app_name", "AppName debug"
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        zipAlignEnabled true
        resValue "string", "app_name", "AppName"
    }
}
```

You can use **@string/app_name** in AndroidManifest.xml files.

Make sure you remove **app_name** from values/ folder (no entry by this name).

Comment: Perfect when the app name has to be read form an external file

Comment: Got an error when building this way. Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.. Duplicate resources: res/values/strings.xml:string/app_name

Comment: If you get:

Got an error when building this way. Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.. Duplicate resources: res/values/strings.xml:string/app_name

you should do, like its written:

"Make sure you remove app_name from values/ folder (no entry by this name)."

Comment: I like this because the strings folder solution (the accepted solution, above) only works if the app name is defined for a particular source set / product flavor. In my case, I'm setting up a Jenkins Pipeline job to build different versions of our app automatically with different names, and not all those names have productFlavors defined for them. So Jenkins simply supplies the app name via the environment, and gradle reads it: `resValue "string", "app_name", System.getenv("APP_NAME") ?: "MyApp"`

Comment: if i removed app_name from string folder then getting error compile time 
 
getting error -Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDevDebugManifest'. > Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Comment: It works, but if you have another library in your application with it's own `strings.xml` and `app_name`, an application will get a value from there. Probably in this case you should change a key `app_name` to other.

Comment: did not work for me with a multi-module setup. play console kept reporting wrong empty icon attribute when in reality it was my app's name! I used this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24785270/how-to-change-app-name-per-gradle-build-type/41301021#41301021

Answer (score 68):

You can do this with gradle:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "My Standard App Name"]
        }
        debug {
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "Debug"]
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your `AndroidManifest.xml` put:

```
<application
    android:label="${appName}"/>
    <activity
        android:label="${appName}">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Note: it also works with `productFlavors`.**

Comment: getting error -Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDevDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Comment: NOT WORKING---buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "GridL Debug"]
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev1"
        }
    }

Comment: this is the only method that worked for me, what's even worse is the error reporting on the play console. it said that my icon was wrong but in reality it was my app name! this helped! Thanks man!!

Answer (score 65):

To support translations make this:

**1.** remove string "app_name"

**2.**  add to gradle

```
 buildTypes {
    admin {
       resValue "string", "app_name", "@string/app_name_admin"
    }
    release {
        resValue "string", "app_name", "@string/app_name_release"
    }
    debug {
        resValue "string", "app_name", "@string/app_name_debug"
    }
}
```

**3.** Set app name in Manifest as "@string/app_name"

**4.** Add to strings.xml values

```
<string name="app_name_admin">App Admin</string>
<string name="app_name_release">App  release</string>
<string name="app_name_debug">App debug</string>
```

Comment: What are the different types of build types ? Other than, admin, release and debug ?

Comment: @DineshVG you can set difference  by yourself, for example different applicationId

Comment: I want to use UIAutomator test in another build configuration other than debug with different pro-guard rules. Is that possible ?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, worked great for me

Comment: I really like this approach because it allows you even to add a custom `app_name` in _productFlavors_ section of `build.gradle` file. An extremely convenient and flexible approach when you need it.

Comment: did not work for me in a multi-module setup. i used this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24785270/how-to-change-app-name-per-gradle-build-type/41301021#41301021 which worked for me!

Comment: I like this answer because it still allows me to reference the generate String in other resources, eg. `<string name="channel_name">@string/app_name</string>`

Answer (score 16):

The app name is user-visible, and that's why Google encourages you to keep it in your strings.xml file. You can define a separate string resource file that contains strings that are specific to your buildTypes. It sounds like you might have a custom `qa` buildType. If that's not true, ignore the qa part below.

```
└── src
    ├── debug
    │   └── res
    │       └── buildtype_strings.xml
    ├── release
    │   └── res
    │       └── buildtype_strings.xml
    └── qa
        └── res
            └── buildtype_strings.xml
```

Comment: did this ever work for you? I documented my example, and it does not work... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26032950/custom-strings-for-debug-buildtype

Comment: these are flavors not build types

Answer (score 16):

We need a solution to support app name with localization (for multi language).
I have tested with @Nick Unuchek solution, but building is failed (not found @string/) . a little bit change to fix this bug:
build.gradle file:

```
android {
    ext{
        APP_NAME = "@string/app_name_default"
        APP_NAME_DEV = "@string/app_name_dev"
    }

    productFlavors{

        prod{
            manifestPlaceholders = [ applicationLabel: APP_NAME]
        }

        dev{
            manifestPlaceholders = [ applicationLabel: APP_NAME_DEV ]
        }

    }
```

values\strings.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name_default">AAA prod</string>
    <string name="app_name_dev">AAA dev</string>

</resources>
```

values-en\strings.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name_default">AAA prod en</string>
    <string name="app_name_dev">AAA dev en</string>

</resources>
```

Manifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:label="${applicationLabel}" >
</application>
```

Comment: A game like "Need for Speed" for example will never be called "Bedürfnis nach Geschwindigkeit" in Germany. Unless it is any rip-off from a dubious developer...

Comment: It working. Thank you so much. However, in my case, I need to add 1 more `tools:replace="android:label"` in `application` in `AndroidManifest`

Answer (score 9):

There are multiple ways you can do.

you can create `manifestPlaceholders` **OR** `resValue` in app level `build.gradle`. e.g.

```
buildTypes {
     release {
          ...
          manifestPlaceholders = [appLabel: "My App"]
          //resValue "string", "appLabel", '"My App"'
     }
     debug {
          ...
          manifestPlaceholders = [appLabel: "My App - Debug"]
          //resValue "string", "appLabel", '"My App - Debug"'
     }
}
```

**OR**

If you have `productFlavors`, you can create there

```
flavorDimensions "env"
productFlavors {
    dev {
        dimension "env"
        ...
        manifestPlaceholders = [appLabel: "My App - Development"]
        //resValue "string", "appLabel", '"My App - Development"'
    }
    prod {
        dimension "env"
        ...
        manifestPlaceholders = [appLabel: "My Awesome App"]
        //resValue "string", "appLabel", '"My Awesome App"'
    }
}
```

Then in `AndroidManifest.xml` if you are using `manifestPlaceholders`, just change `android:label="${appLabel}"` as below **OR** if you are using `resValue`, just change `android:label=@string/appLabel`

```
<application
    ...
    android:label="${appLabel}"> //OR `android:label=@string/appLabel`
    
    <activity
        ...
        android:label="${appLabel}">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**NOTE:** Make sure to change `android:label` as well in `<activity>` of `LAUNCHER` category. If it doesn't require to use `android:label` in `<activity>`, just remove this.

---

If you do not want to add in `build.gradle` directly, you can add in `values/string.xml` of selected `ProductFlavors`. e.g.

**Add**

```
<string name="appLabel">My App - Development</string>
```

in `app/src/dev/res/values/string.xml`

and

```
<string name="appLabel">My Awesome App</string>
```

in `app/src/prod/res/values/string.xml`

Comment: Best answer by a country mile, allows to set all app name variants you want directly from Gradle (as per the question), rather than hunting down all the separate res folders. *Especially useful* if you may have dynamic app names, coming from build config.

Answer (score 5):

For a more dynamic gradle based solution (e.g. set a base Application name in main's `strings.xml` once, and avoid repeating yourself in each flavor / build type combination's `strings.xml`), see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32220436/1128600

Answer (score 4):

You can use `strings.xml` in different folders, see [Android separate string values for release and debug builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36039848/android-separate-string-values-for-release-and-debug-builds).

So, create this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Your app name</string>
</resources>
```

Then paste it to `app\src\debug\res\values\` and `app\src\release\res\values\` folders. Replace "Your app name" in debug and release files. Remove `app_name` item from `strings.xml` in `app\src\main\res\values\` folder.

In `AndroidManifest` you will have the same

```
<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    ...
```

No changes at all. Even if you added a library with it's `AndroidManifest` file and `strings.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

As author asks to do this in *Gradle*, we can assume he want to do it in the script and not in the configuration files. Since both *Android Studio* and *Gradle* has been heavily updated and modified in the last year (~2018) all other answers above, seem overly contorted. The easy-peasy way, is to add the following to your `app/build.gradle`:

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        ...
        // Rename/Set default APK name prefix (app*.apk --> AwesomeApp*.apk)
        android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all { output ->
                def appName = "AwesomeApp"
                outputFileName = appName+"-${output.baseName}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP is asking to change the Application Name not APK name.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your build-specific folder e.g development, Staging and

1-Add res folder.

2-Add values folder inside res folder.

3-Add strings.xml.

4-Add app_name string and change the name here.

repeat the same for other build types if you want to change for others.

Now you will get your app name as per your specific build type.