# custom strings for debug buildType

Tags: android, gradle

I have an android app and I want to change the app label for the debug and other **buildTypes**. I don´t have any flavors!

Here is the setup that I believe looks like it should work:
[image: Android Studio Setup]

```
-src
   |-debug
      |-res
         |-values
            |-strings.xml
   |-main
      |-res
         |-values
            |-strings.xml
      |-java
      [...]
```

I have no custom sourcesets just a debug buildType:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"

    }
}
```

so I though

```
sourceSets.debug.res.srcDirs = ['src/debug/res']
```

would to the trick. But it doesn't. Any ideas?

[How to change app name per Gradle build type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24785270/how-to-change-app-name-per-gradle-build-type) does not work anymore...

Answer (score 24):

I found another sweet solution to this, using manifest placeholders:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<application
    android:label="${applicationLabel}">
    <activity
        android:label="${applicationLabel}">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

and in your gradle file:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders = [ applicationLabel:"@string/app_name"]
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            manifestPlaceholders = [ applicationLabel:"MyApp Debug"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for anyone who sees merge error in gradle build, simple add ````tools:replace="android:label" tools:node="replace"```` inside <application>

Answer (score 13):

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        resValue 'string', 'APP_NAME', '"My App Release"'
    }
    debug {
        resValue 'string', 'APP_NAME', '"My App Debug"'
    }
}
```

value\strings.xml

< string name="app_name" >@string/APP_NAME< /string>

and use app_name everywhere

Comment: Thanks! This works great. However I use 'app_name' instead of 'APP_NAME'

Comment: Actually you do not need to create that resource in strings.xml. When you define that in `buildTypes`, that string resources already exists, you can directly reference it from layout xml as well.

Comment: For me this _method_ worked `resValue('string', 'app_name', 'my app name')` instead of `resValue 'string' 'app_name' 'my app name'`

Answer (score 4):

You have to use

```
   |-debug
      |-res
         |-values
            |-strings.xml
```

In **your picture** you have debug/res/strings.xml

Also you doens't need it (because it is the standard, but the issue isn't here).

```
sourceSets.debug.res.srcDirs = ['src/debug/res']
```

Comment: Fixed the screenshot, that one was an old one. Not it is the real screenshot. I did not understand your answer, what Do I need to do to make it work?

Comment: In this case, it seems to be correct. I really don't know the reason.

Answer (score 4):

Forget the string.xml files. All can be easily configured in build.gradle.

First of all, you should maintain the string pointer "app_name" in AndroidManifest file, and delete all instances of "app_name" in string's resource files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<application
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Secondly, the resource value of *@string/app_name* is currently not defined. So we must apply its default definition in build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 123423432
        versionName "1.0.0"
        resValue 'string', 'app_name', '"My app label"'
    }
```

Currently, app_name is defined for all build types. By assuming you want to change the app label for the **buildTypes**, each build type must be defined with a string value in the same build.gradle branch:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        resValue 'string', 'app_name', '"My app label Release"'
    }
    debug {
        resValue 'string', 'app_name', '"My app label Debug"'
    }
}
```

Since this resource value is set programmatically, we also need to add a certain translations lint ignore in case of a **Release** build:

```
lintOptions { disable 'MissingTranslation' }
```

In case you want to change it accordingly with a set of defined Flavours(dev, qua or prd) add the resValues definitions in *productFlavours* instead of *buildTypes*:

```
productFlavors {
    dev {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp.dev"
        resValue 'string', 'app_name', '"My app label Dev"'
    }
    qua {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp.qua"
        resValue 'string', 'app_name', '"My app label Qua"'
    }
    prd {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp.prd"
        resValue 'string', 'app_name', '"My app label Prd"'
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, but how to deal with the internationalization? English, Chinese or German language?

Comment: Why not build types? I am using build types and it does not seem like it's replacing the string

Answer (score 2):

You can create a string in gradle that will be available in xml too:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "String", "app_name", "AppDebug"
    }
    release {
        buildConfigField "String", "app_name", "AppRelease"
    }
```

And then use it in xml:

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

Just make sure `app_name` not specified in your `strings.xml`.

Comment: This doesn't work, better use: resValue "string", "app_name", '"MyAppDebug"' instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }
    sourceSets.debug.resources.srcDirs = ['src/debug/res']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you remembered to get rid of the directory listing inside your app's build.gradle?

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDir 'src'
//      res.srcDir 'res' <--- This line should be removed
        assets.srcDir 'assets'
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite an old question, but I've had the same problem and just solved it.

You should update these codes if you have one in your `build.gradle` for your app.

```
debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
release.setRoot('build-types/release')
```

These codes automatically generate your `AppName.iml` and set default debug and release directory to `/build-types/debug/res`, which is different from `src/debug/res`.