# Android separate string values for release and debug builds

Tags: android, gradle, android-build, android-build-flavors

Every time i release my app i change all my **url strings** and some **keys** from testing to production. The way I do it is just comment out the testing strings before i release. Is there a better way to handle strings based on the build type ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197636/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-variable-in-gradle-usable-in-java

Comment: was searching for this one.. great question and answer..

Comment: Do not do that. Chances of having incorrect strings in production code with your approach are pretty high.
Do it this way:
http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

Comment: @RusheelJain is there a solution for just android resource values ?

Comment: @spaceMonkey Yes the link I gave you. I know this because I tried it myself today only :P

I wrote the steps in the answer below. Let me know if something is unclear :)

Answer (score 57):

Assuming you use Android Studio, by default the system creates a basic `release` and `debug` flavor. So if you add a `debug` and `release` folder in the `app/src` folder of your project you can declare separate values there.

So your structure should be like this:

```
project
  -app
    -src
      -debug
        -java
          ...
        -res
          -values
            -strings.xml
      -release
        -java
          ...
        -res
          -values
            -strings.xml
      -main
        -java
          ...
        -res
          -values
            -strings.xml
```

I should also add that if you have a string which isn't defined in either of the `debug` or the `release` folder that it will fallback to your `main` folder.

Comment: so every time i work on something should i update all 3 folders ?

Comment: what about seperating the url specific strings into a seperate "url-strings.xml" and then having `project/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml`
`project/app/src/debug/res/values/url-strings.xml`
`project/app/src/release/res/values/url-strings.xml`

Comment: nope, you just have your app in your default `main` folder. Any resource that needs to be different in `debug` or `release` builds you just add to the strings.xml (or as @k3b mentioned a different file). Android Studio will always fallback on the `main` folder so you can have 1 url string in the `debug`/`release` folders and it will only take those.

Comment: I had to use this for **admob ad units** which I created in 3 new resource files (for main, debug and release). In my case, having a release version wasn't necessary, although I still created it anyway. But I made the release and main versions of `admob.xml` same (copy and paste) cos I was porting to other OSes which only recognised the files in the main folder.

Comment: Also make sure to change build variant in Android Studio to manage everything integrated

Answer (score 8):

Well, you can use Gradle if needs to use for a few strings

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        resValue 'string', 'adUnitIdMain', '"production-id-value-should-be-here"'
        resValue 'string', 'adUnitIdList', '"production-id-value-should-be-here"'
        resValue 'string', 'adUnitIdDetail', '"production-id-value-should-be-here"'
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        resValue 'string', 'adUnitIdMain', '"test-id-value-should-be-here"'
        resValue 'string', 'adUnitIdList', '"test-id-value-should-be-here"'
        resValue 'string', 'adUnitIdDetail', '"test-id-value-should-be-here"'
    }
}
```

Comment: For those which want to know more about `resValue` you can read up in the DSL document here: https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.html as linked by Google Documentation here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#build-types

Comment: I was looking for a place to put my adMob unit ids, and this is the perfect place instead of  strings.xml. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just make two flavors in build.gradle. Then two directories, again as given in the link ([developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html) ).
Since you need only strings to be altered, just copy your strings.xml files into the new directories (i.e. dev and production)
Delete your original strings.xml

And thats it. :)

No need to move your java files or other layout files.

In short, leave everything in your 'main' directory that should be consistent across all build flavors.
Override the values dependent upon build flavor into their respective directory.

Comment: build flavours? do you mean "build types" or "product flavours"?

Comment: sorry. yes product flavors like testing and production