# Android studio - build and run configurations

Tags: android, string, android-studio

I'd like to have different configurations for debug and release versions. For the most part, By configuration I mean having different **string constants**,

e.g. **connection strings**. Additionally I'd like to have a running configuration to be connected to a build configuration, so that when I select 'release' from the running dropdown, the correct version is automatically built. Is that even possible? Is there a way to use a different string resource file based on build configuration?

Comment: yes you can define different string files for debug and release.Create `release` folder. Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36042309/6005977)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a product flavors functionality available in android studio. You have to add different flavors for your application in the app level build.gradle file. You can set them as follows:

```
  productFlavors {
    sandbox {
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        applicationId "com.abc.sandbox"
        buildConfigField 'String', 'HOST', '"http://api/v1/"'
    }

    development {
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        applicationId "com.abc.development"
        buildConfigField 'String', 'HOST', '"http://api/v1/"'
    }

    production {
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        applicationId "com.abc.production"
        buildConfigField 'String', 'HOST', '"http://api/v1/"'
    }
```

}

You can run respective flavor by selecting it from build versions before running your application.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about buildConfigField, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate strings.xml for debug mode and add your strings to it.

1. Right click `res` folder in your projects direcotry -> new -> Android Resource File.
2. In the new window, Enter `filename` (strings.xml or any other file you need), select `debug` in `Source Set` as shown in image, click OK.
3. Add your required data here in this new file as,
    `<string name="same_key_as_in_original">Value</string>`

[image]