# There is a way to rewrite android @string behaviour?

Tags: android, xml, string, android-layout

I explain my goal of this post.

Actualy, I want to rewrite how android works basicaly, with strings in app.
At this moment, i can change dynamicaly it from rewritting the android ressources & context, but when i refer directly a string in xml ( `@string/name` ), the `getString` function in Ressources class isnt called. But when i do pragmaticaly a `getString(R.string.my_string)` in my Fragment / Activity, `getString` from Ressources class is called.

Actualy, i have this and i works good only when i use `getString(R.string.my_string)`  :

```kotlin
class MyRessources(
    res: Resources?,
    private val context: Context?
) : Resources(res?.assets, res?.displayMetrics, res?.configuration) {

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    override fun getString(id: Int): String {

        var identifier = id

        val entryName = getResourceEntryName(id)

        context?.let {

            val name = entryName.plus("__test")

            identifier = getIdentifier(name, "string", getResourcePackageName(id))

            if (identifier == 0) {
                identifier = id
            }
        }

        return super.getString(identifier)
    }
}
```

There is a simple way, with not much code, to do overwrite of that `@string` behavior in xml ?

Answer (score 0):

it works for you in `Fragment`, because you are probably creating in there your custom `MyRessources` instance and obtaining `String` through it

```
new MyResources(resources, context).getString(...)
```

there is no option for overriding `@string/resname`, this will always use original `resources` of an app

if you want to override some `String`s only for some tests (e.g. for debug) then consider creating separated flavor for this purpose and/or read [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36039848/android-separate-string-values-for-release-and-debug-builds) topic