# Custom strings file

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm wondering if there is a way to force getting strings from the custom file? Let's say I would like to have testing strings set and use them in the debug mode. As far as I know, there is no possibility to create a custom Locale and use for example `values-test` folder. But maybe there is the possibility to override something and force getting strings from the assets folder file?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to separate string resources between release and debug - just separate them in folders (check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36042309/9093586)):

```
project
  -app
    -src
      -debug
        -java
          ...
        -res
          -values
            -strings.xml
      -release
        -java
          ...
        -res
          -values
            -strings.xml
      -main
        -java
          ...
        -res
          -values
            -strings.xml
```

But if you want to override string resources there is great and useful library [Restring](https://github.com/B3nedikt/restring).

You can put your own string resources to it and it will replace your default ones. Successfully used in project with 10M+ installs.

Comment: Well, I want to have the possibility to jump between languages while using the app so building debug version with the specific strings is not a good idea. I will look into this library, thanks a lot.

Comment: why not?) create strings-en.xml etc. in both release and debug folder> And it will work fine :)

Comment: create strings for all languages you want and put them in both release and debug

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in **build.gradle(app)** by using following snipped of code.

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            resValue 'string', 'api_key', '"000000000"'
        }
        release {
            resValue 'string', 'api_key', '"123456789"'
        }
    }
}
```

#### **Usage (Java)**

```
val text = resources.getString(R.string.api_key)
Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

#### **Usage (Kotlin)**

```
String text = resources.getString(R.string.api_key)
Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Add this, **sync** your project & **build** your project. You may seem red warning, ignore that and use it.

No need to manually check for BuildConfigs.